# Position of compiler flag -l

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, opencl, compiler-flags

I'm currently learning OpenCL. Now, when I want to compile my program, I get an error with this command:

```
g++ -Wall -l OpenCL main.cpp -o main
```

The errors are mostly undefined references, because the library is not linked, I think (nevertheless I will post the error code at the end).

But with this command everything works fine:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main -l OpenCL
```

So my question is, what do I have to do, to use the -l Flag in front of the command?
(The Background is: I want to use Netbeans to compile my programm and when i add the flag under  -> properties -> build -> C++ Compiler -> additional options, it will put in in the Position, shown in the first command)

Thanks in advance for your help

Here's the error code:

```
/tmp/ccmKP4oI.o: In function `cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<_cl_context*>::release(_cl_context*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cl6detail16ReferenceHandlerIP11_cl_contextE7releaseES3_[_ZN2cl6detail16ReferenceHandlerIP11_cl_contextE7releaseES3_]+0x14): undefined reference to `clReleaseContext'
/tmp/ccmKP4oI.o: In function `cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<_cl_command_queue*>::release(_cl_command_queue*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cl6detail16ReferenceHandlerIP17_cl_command_queueE7releaseES3_[_ZN2cl6detail16ReferenceHandlerIP17_cl_command_queueE7releaseES3_]+0x14): undefined reference to `clReleaseCommandQueue'
/tmp/ccmKP4oI.o: In function `cl::Platform::getInfo(unsigned int, std::string*) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cl8Platform7getInfoEjPSs[_ZNK2cl8Platform7getInfoEjPSs]+0x22): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformInfo'
/tmp/ccmKP4oI.o: In function `cl::Platform::get(std::vector<cl::Platform, std::allocator<cl::Platform> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cl8Platform3getEPSt6vectorIS0_SaIS0_EE[_ZN2cl8Platform3getEPSt6vectorIS0_SaIS0_EE]+0x41): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cl8Platform3getEPSt6vectorIS0_SaIS0_EE[_ZN2cl8Platform3getEPSt6vectorIS0_SaIS0_EE]+0xb4): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Add it in "libraries" rather than "additional options"…

Comment: In short, the symbols are resolved in the order you list them, if you want main.cpp to be able to use symbols in libOpenCL, you need to list it before the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of [most] arguments to `g++` is very important.

Libraries should go last (at least after source and object files). You can't really change that.

The `-l`  should preferably be *glued* to the library name:

```
 g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main -lOpenCL
 #                          ^^^ glue the -l to the library name
```

You probably want to also pass `-g` (in addition of `-Wall`) to the compiler to get a debuggable binary. Use the `gdb` debugger.

<sup>As [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) commented, you might want to replace `-g` with `-ggdb` if using specifically `gdb`.</sup>

Comment: The order of _some_ arguments is very important.  Not all.  And with g++, whether you glue it to the name or not is purely a question of taste.  (Historically, Unix linkers required it to be glued, but this is not the case of g++.)

Comment: Agreed. But overall, the order of arguments is important. You cannot permute them.

Comment: On Linux (and some other systems), `-g` and `-ggdb`.  On other systems, however, `-ggdb` will provide extra information, which only `gdb` understands (and which may crash the native debugger).  If you know that you will be using `gdb` (my recommendation as well), `-ggdb` may be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

With g++ (and generally under Unix), `-l` specifies a source of
input (either a `.a` or a `.so`), and input is processed in
order.  When the input is a static library (a `.a` file), it
will be scanned for objects which resolve undefined references;
if it is a `.so`, there aren't any object files in it, but it
will still only be taken into consideration if it resolves some
undefined symbol.

When you put the `-l` before any object files, there are no
undefined symbols yet, so nothing will be incorporated into the
program.